# Figures in Two columns

Tags: floats, subfloats, two-column, figure-placement

I'm using overleaf. It's two column and I need 6 figures comes one by one. two figures in column 1 and another 4 in column 2.

Comment: And what's the problem? Can you please show a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) of what you've tried?

Comment: I want to put six figures in two columns overleaf. But the left column half-page gap is theirs. all six are arranged together one by one. I want two figures one by one in the left column and the remaining in the right column.

Comment: Sorry, but we cannot answer this question without more information. Currently we are not knowing, what you are doing. So we cannot know, why you fail in getting, what you want. Please see the link in my first comment. BTW: I doubt, that the question really depends on Overleaf. It seems to be a general LaTeX problem, maybe with placing floats, maybe only adding images. But we wouldn't need to guess this too, if you'd show a minimal working example. And there isn't a "two column overleaf". There are several classes and several templates supporting two column document.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a general problem in having two figures in the left column and four in the right column of a two column document:

```latex
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}

An example with two figures in the first column.

\begin{figure}[htp]
  \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{First figure}
  \bigskip
  \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Second figure}
\end{figure}

The second column has four figures.

\begin{figure}[htp]
  \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth,height=.17\textheight]{example-image-b}
  \caption{Third figure}
  \bigskip
  \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth,height=.17\textheight]{example-image-c}
  \caption{Fourth figure}
  \bigskip  
  \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth,height=.17\textheight]{example-image}
  \caption{Fifth figure}
  \bigskip
  \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth,height=.17\textheight]{example-image}
  \caption{Sixth figure}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

So if you have a problem in getting two images in the left column and four in the right column, you have to show, what you've tried. To do so, you should add a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) to your question.